# Generate a serial number whose probability to be guessed is less than 1/1000

Tags: random

I'm asked to generate random serial numbers whose probability to be guessed is less than 1/1000. How to find out in which range should these numbers be ?

Comment: Why not $[0,1000]$?  All you need is a uniform choice amongst any set with more than $1000$ numbers in it.

Comment: So if I need to apply such a serial number on 1 million products per year, does it mean that I need to generate a serial number between 0 and 1 billion to keep the probability to be guessed (for one year) below 1/1000

Comment: Not following.  If you choose an integer from $0$ to $1000$ then I have a $\frac 1{1001}$ probability of guessing it correctly.  That is what you asked for.  Not sure what you are asking now.

Comment: Do you want there to be less than a $\frac1{1000}$ chance of _any_ two out of a million products having the same serial number when the numbers are chosen entirely randomly and independently? Then you need to pick from a rather large range of numbers indeed.

Comment: Sorry, I have some difficulty to translate my mind in a clear question. I need to apply serial numbers on products and I want to keep the probability of guessing the serial number below 1/1000. I produce 1 million products per year and I assign a serial number to each product. My conclusion would be that I need to generate serial numbers in [0, 1 billion[ in order to keep the probability of guessing any serial number below 1/1000, is this correct ?

Comment: So:  you assign serial numbers to your $N$ products, I guess a number, and you want me to have less than $\frac 1{1000}$ probability of naming a serial number which you used?  Then, yes, you need more than $1000\times N$ possible numbers.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of clarity and completeness, I'll move the comments into an answer.

The simplest model that satisfies your constraint is to pick a number between 0 and 1000 (inclusive). As there are 1001 possible choices, the chance of guess is $\frac{1}{1001}$ which is less than $ \frac{1}{1000}$.

Clearly, any set of at least 1001 distinct integers also suffices.

Comment: Thanks. When I do this --- take lots of other people's comments (and perhaps some of my own) and make them an answer -- I usually mark the answer "Community Wiki", so that I don't get any points when it's marked correct, but so that OP has a chance to mark an answer as correct and "close out" the question.